# Groupby and plot bar graph

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, bar-chart

I want to plot a bar graph for sales over period of year. x-axis as `'year'` and y-axis as sum of weekly sales per year. While plotting I am getting `'KeyError: 'year'`. I guess it's because `'year'` became index during group by.

Below is the sample content from `csv` file:

```
Store   year    Weekly_Sales
1   2014    24924.5
1   2010    46039.49
1   2015    41595.55
1   2010    19403.54
1   2015    21827.9
1   2010    21043.39
1   2014    22136.64
1   2010    26229.21
1   2014    57258.43
1   2010    42960.91
```

Below is the code I used to group by

```
storeDetail_df = pd.read_csv('Details.csv')
result_group_year= storeDetail_df.groupby(['year'])
total_by_year = result_group_year['Weekly_Sales'].agg([np.sum])

total_by_year.plot(kind='bar' ,x='year',y='sum',rot=0)
```

**Updated the Code and below is the output:**
DataFrame output:

```
   year          sum
0  2010  42843534.38
1  2011  45349314.40
2  2012  35445927.76
3  2013         0.00
```

below is the Graph i am getting:
[image]

Comment: Can you add `storeDetail_df = storeDetail_df.reset_index()` after `storeDetail_df = pd.read_csv('Details.csv')` and then try plotting? I will have to put your data manually as a code in DatFrame so I can't try it myself

Comment: When i Print and checked 'storeDetail_df '. I am seeing seperate Index column apart from the above mentioned column

Comment: Ok, check my answer below. `delim_whitespace=True` solves the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While reading your `csv` file, you needed to use white space as the delimiter as `delim_whitespace=True` and then reset the index after summing up the `Weekly_Sales`. Below is the working code:

```
storeDetail_df = pd.read_csv('Details.csv', delim_whitespace=True)
result_group_year= storeDetail_df.groupby(['year'])
total_by_year = result_group_year['Weekly_Sales'].agg([np.sum]).reset_index()
total_by_year.plot(kind='bar' ,x='year',y='sum',rot=0,  legend=False)
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: my sum value is actually (42843534.38,45349314.40,35445927.76) but in graph y axis value is shown as (1,2,3,4). I checked in eclipse and in jupyter notebook.Something i need to do in the code to show the exact or approximate values?

Comment: That’s strange I just used the same values which you provided. Can you print the data frame  before plotting it to see if the sum values are correct

Comment: I have added the data Frame output and the Output graph in original Post.Please Check

Comment: Can you also tell me what version of pandas are you using? It’s strange how you are getting different values

Comment: You posted a new question. I just saw it. Hope you got your answer

Answer (score 0):

In case it is making year your index due to group by command. you need to remove it as a index before plotting.
Try

```
total_by_year = total_by_year.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this

```
storeDetail_df = pd.read_csv('Details.csv')
result_group_year= storeDetail_df.groupby(['year'])['Weekly_Sales'].sum()

result_group_year = result_group_year.reset_index(drop=False)
result_group_year.plot.bar(x='year', y='Weekly_Sales')
```

Comment: Naah, doesn't work. `read_csv` requires a delimiter as white spaces.  Yo get a `KeyError: 'year'` in the second line